# Getting number of svn revision

Tags: c#, svn, keyword

how can I get only number of revision with using `"$LastChangedRevision: $"` keyword? 
I want to use it in AssemblyInfo.cs - in `[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]` 
because this keyword returns me string `"LastChangedRevision: (numberOfRevision)"` instead of number only
thanks!

Comment: Another way is to generate that line as a pre-build step. The file can be generated with subwcrev.

Comment: The keyword you mention (or any subversion substitute ) will only be updated when committing the file. And perhaps you want revision to be the latest revision of all code in the assembly? But that's not what you are asking for, or?

Answer (score -3):

`$WCREV$` - This will give you the revision number only

**UPDATE**

Actually you will need a template (`AssemblyInfo.cs.tmpl`) for your `AssemblyInfo.cs` which will have the AssemblyInfo.cs contents with the `SubWCRev` keyword. And you have to add a command to your pre-build action to update your `AssemblyInfo.cs` from the template file.

Please look at that [this link](http://robertsmyth.blogspot.com/2009/04/using-subversion-revision-as.html) for complete walk through.

Comment: is there any way how to add it into - [assembly: AssemblyVersion("0.0.0.1")] ? because if I use [assembly: AssemblyVersion("0.0.0.$WCREV$")] it wont build

Comment: This goes with [subwcrev](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-subwcrev-keywords.html) if you want to generate the code. It is not a [substitute keyword](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s02.html#svn-ch-7-sect-2.3.4)

Comment: @erikH If you have any solution then please provide - I am also eager to know and I guess putting revision number on assembly info does have any proper way

Comment: @MunimAbdul I don't know the way Martin wants it. I'm interested to, after digging and not finding a way... (I currently do it with subwcrev and generate the file at build, not at commit. Which by the way works fine.)

Comment: @erikH Probably you haven't read my updated answer. It was my bad not mentioning the details